# C++ libtins "An invalid handle was specified"

Tags: c++, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to get into using the libtins library for C++, and keep running into a basic error.

This is my code:

```
#define TINS_STATIC
#define WIN32

#include <iostream>
#include <tins/tins.h>

using namespace Tins;

int main(void) {

    NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface::default_interface();
    Sniffer sniffer(iface.name());

    //more code below
}
```

And I get the following error during runtime:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD80F7DC9A (ntdll.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

My default network interface is "Ethernet 2". Libtins can successfully detect this when I list all interfaces.

```
{07C8C0D2-A2FC-4B91-9875-A8301682EF7C} (Ethernet 2)
```

I tried manually putting in the interface name as such:

```
Sniffer sniffer("\\Device\\NPF_{07C8C0D2-A2FC-4B91-9875-A8301682EF7C}");
```

But get this error during runtime:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD7D2EA388 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Tins::pcap_error at memory location 0x000000543FCFF790.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD7D2EA388 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Tins::pcap_error at memory location 0x000000543FCFF790.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it related to my network configuration? I'm on a Windows 10 machine using the prebuilt 64 bit libtins library. Wireshark can sniff on the the interface with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the name of your interface is `\\Device\\NPF_{07C8C0D2-A2FC-4B91-9875-A8301682EF7C}`. As far as I know, since your interface is Ethernet 2 than you should pass `eth2` to the `Sniffer` object.

Following works perfect for me:

```
SnifferConfiguration config;
config.set_promisc_mode(true);
config.set_filter("udp and (dst port 53 or src port 53)");

Sniffer sniffer("wlp9s0", config);

sniffer.sniff_loop(callback);
```

Comment: Hello, I think that solution works for Linux, but on Windows I'm supposed to extract the name of the device programatically as described [here](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/windows)

The only problem is that I'm still getting this exception which doesn't appear to affect the functionality (if I ignore the exception everything runs fine), just annoying.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. However, I will leave the answer. Maybe someone finds it useful in the future.